# Is there a desktop icon for Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

Is there a desktop icon short cut for Google contacts? 
I've seen all kinds of answers, but none to the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official one.

I made an option, it's not great:
http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/add-a-google-contacts-button-to-blog-website-or-desktop.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you make a desktop icon for the URL https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts